# ASP.Net: Ignore Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I have an application where I need to use 'Basic Authentication'; however, in order for you to debug the application in Visual Studio, IIS requires the directory to also have 'Windows Authentication' enabled.

The problem is my user handler tries to send out a request for basic authentication to compare them to a database... but the basic authentication request is pushed down in priority by the NTLM request IIS inserts into the header due to the above 'Windows Authentication', and so that'll get sent to the server by the user instead.

Has anyone ran into this situation before?  Is there a way to debug in Visual Studio without having windows authentication on (or at least keep it from requesting the security for requests)?

Thanks!

Edit: Forgot to mention, outside of the development environment, 'windows authentication' would not be on

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to debug?

Comment: a simple Asp.Net 2.0 application (nothing out of the ordinary)

Comment: Weird...I've never heard of VS requiring Windows Auth in order to debug? Is it giving you a specific error message saying that Debug is required? Have you tried just attaching to the proccess directly?

Comment: Here's the error you'd get: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. Debugging failed because integrated Windows authentication is not enabled. Please see Help for assistance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check it...](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/12/28/Fix-problems-with-Visual-Studio-F5-debugging-of-ASP.NET-applications-on-IIS7-Vista.aspx)

I always used to debug my web apps by just attaching to the process.